# Django Rest Framework - Posting multiple objects with many=True raise AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to override the create method of a ListCreateAPIView to be able to post multiple objects at the same time. The items are saved correctly but I keep getting an error.

I am using Django 1.10.4 and DRF 3.5.3

models.py :

```
class Genre(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
     category = models.ForeignKey(GenreCategory, related_name='genres', blank=True, null=True)
     active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py :

```
class GenreList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Genre.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GenreInputSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = GenreOutputSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

serializers.py :

```
class GenreInputSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Genre
        fields = ('name', 'category',)
```

POST request data (via the browsable API) :

```
[
    {
        "name": "Reggae",
        "category": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Blues",
        "category": null
    }
]
```

And here is the Traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/malastas/Documents/museekenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/malastas/Documents/museekenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/malastas/Documents/museekenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
response = response.render()
  File "/Users/malastas/Documents/museekenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 109, in render
self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/malastas/Documents/museekenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 72, in rendered_content
ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "/Users/malastas/Documents/museekenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 701, in render
context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
  File "/Users/malastas/Documents/museekenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 674, in get_context
'post_form': self.get_rendered_html_form(data, view, 'POST', request),
  File "/Users/malastas/Documents/museekenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 507, in get_rendered_html_form
return self.render_form_for_serializer(serializer)
  File "/Users/malastas/Documents/museekenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 515, in render_form_for_serializer
serializer.data,
  File "/Users/malastas/Documents/museekenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 527, in data
ret = super(Serializer, self).data
  File "/Users/malastas/Documents/museekenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 266, in data
self._data = self.get_initial()
  File "/Users/malastas/Documents/museekenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 399, in get_initial
for field_name, field in self.fields.items()
  File "/Users/malastas/Documents/museekenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 400, in <listcomp>
if (field.get_value(self.initial_data) is not empty) and
  File "/Users/malastas/Documents/museekenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 435, in get_value
return dictionary.get(self.field_name, empty)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

The objects are saved correctly but the error is then raised during the Response, when accessing serializer.data

I've seen a lot of examples for posting mutiple objects with only the many=True, so I don't understand why this raises an error, do you have any idea ?

Comment: Which versions of django and drf are you using ?

Comment: `serializer = GenreOutputSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': request})` mind to change this to `serializer = GenreOutputSerializer(queryset, many=True)`?

Comment: I have to use the context because of the url field in the output serializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bet is the error is because the BrowsableAPI tries to display a form that matches the serializer it gets from the Response and fails because it doesn't expects a list.

You should try to perform the request as pure JSON and it should work.
Note that your content should be created though the proper response has failed.

Comment: You were right, just tested this as pure json request and it doesn't raise any error, so I guess I'm stuck with this error when testing the API with the UI ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

hi try this on your def list :

```
def list(self, request):
    queryset = self.get_queryset()
    serializer = GenreOutputSerializer(queryset, many=True,safe=False, context={'request': request})
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: safe is not a valid argument for a serializer, raises exception :

__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'safe'